# Audit Trail Plugin installed using BuildConfig is not creating the audit columns

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 2.2.4 and audit-trail plugin 2.0.3.

I previously installed the plugin using the deprecated "grails install-plugin" and it works.  But now I try using BuildConfig.  I have this configuration:

```
plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.2"
    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"
    compile ':cache:1.0.1'
    runtime ":audit-trail:2.0.3"
    runtime ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
}
```

But now the columns for createdBy, editedBy, createdDate and editedDate are not created in the database for domain with annotation @gorm.AuditStamp

My Config.groovy has this:

```
grails {
    plugin{
        audittrail{
            createdBy.field = "createdBy"
            editedBy.field = "editedBy"
            createdDate.field = "createdDate"
            editedDate.field = "editedDate"
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the plugin in `compile` scope

`compile ":audit-trail:2.0.3"`

so that the AST transformation would kick in at compile time to add the configured fields to the domain class.